# UNIX, how to remove comments from several files?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have several `C` programs that contain comment line at the beginning of each program. the lines begin with /* followed by the first line of comment, but the terminator line has */ as the `only` characters in the line. Can you please tell me a way to Remove these comments from all files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find -name '*.c'
```

Use this to verify you're working on the right files.

```
find -name '*.c' | xargs sed -i '0,/^*\/$/d'
```

This will delete up to and including the first line containing only the terminator.

Answer (score 1):

This deletes lines starting with `/*` thorough the first match of `*/` (which must be the comment terminator, regardless of whether its line starts with an extra space or not):

```
sed '/^\/\*/,/\*\//d' < inputfile
```

Comment: The OP apparently wants to remove only the first comment block. Your answer will remove all of them. There's no need to use redirection, `sed` will accept a filename as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

One (ugly) way is to use `cpp`, the C pre-processor. E.g.:

```
$ echo "AAA ; /* hahaha */ " | cpp -
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "<stdin>"
AAA ;
```

While the output is semantically exactly the same as your input, `cpp` will replace all your preprocessor directives, which is probably not what you want. On the other hand, it is *very* good at what it does.